# Can an app fail to write a file due to lack of available memory?

Tags: ios, memory, file-io

Does any app automatically get a certain amount of storage space on install?  I mean, could a newly-installed app go to save a small amount of data in the Documents directory and have that save fail due to insufficient memory available?

I've gotten a bug report that I am pretty sure stems from a failed call to NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: toFile: but I'm now realizing there's no way to get any more information on that fail, it just returns YES or NO.

Answer (score 0):

No. On modern systems saving a file does not take up memory.

What takes up memory is the program that wants to save the file and eventually stores the files contents to memory to be written later.